# Crash when calling Looper.quit()

Tags: android

I have a Android IntentService that connects to a web service to download some jobs in json format. These are then parsed and put into a SQLite3 DB.

The following code (with the sensitive bits added back in) worked on the emulator but never worked on the actual device.

```
public class FetchJobsService extends IntentService {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "FetchJobsService";

    public FetchJobsService() {
        super("FetchJobsService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetch Jobs Service Started");

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Add params to send in the request!
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(params);

        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put(Constants.DATA, jsonData.toString());


        client.post(Constants.FETCH_JOBS, requestParams,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject returnObj = new JSONObject(new String(bytes));
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Success! Jobs downloaded");
                        JSONObject dataObj = returnObj.getJSONObject(Constants.DATA);
                        JSONArray jobs = dataObj.getJSONArray(Constants.JOBS);
                        // Do something with the data downloaded!
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failure! Jobs not successfully downloaded", e);
                    } 
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes,
                                      Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Failure! Status Code: " + statusCode);
                }
            }
        );

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetch Jobs Service Finished");
    }
}
```

It complained about posting to a Dead Thread. After some reading around, I added a Looper to keep the IntentService around until the data had been downloaded and parsed, as such:

```
public class FetchJobsService extends IntentService {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "FetchJobsService";

    public FetchJobsService() {
        super("FetchJobsService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetch Jobs Service Started");

        if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Add params to send in the request!
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(params);

        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put(Constants.DATA, jsonData.toString());


        client.post(Constants.FETCH_JOBS, requestParams,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject returnObj = new JSONObject(new String(bytes));
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Success! Jobs downloaded");
                        JSONObject dataObj = returnObj.getJSONObject(Constants.DATA);
                        JSONArray jobs = dataObj.getJSONArray(Constants.JOBS);
                        // Do something with the data downloaded!
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failure! Jobs not successfully downloaded", e);
                    } finally {
                        if (Looper.myLooper() != null) {
                            Looper.myLooper().quit();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes,
                                      Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Failure! Status Code: " + statusCode);
                    if (Looper.myLooper() != null) {
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }
            }
        );


        Looper.loop();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetch Jobs Service Finished");
    }
}
```

The jobs are now downloaded successfully however the call to `quit()` or `quitSafely()` causes a crash `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1)`.

If I remove the calls to quit() then there is no crash but obviously the service is then not going to stop and release resources until the application quits.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IntentService is meant to handle its own lifecycle. You just override the `onHandleIntent` callback and do what you need to do - once this method exits the IntentService will shut itself down.

The IntentService is already running in a seperate thread, so it doesn't make sense to make the request asynchronously. You should execute your network call synchronously within the `onHandleIntent` callback. There are some examples in [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

You could try something along these lines:

```
HttpEntity requestEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);

//set up post request
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.addHeader(requestEntity.getContentType());
post.setEntity(requestEntity);

//get http client
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParams = mHttpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);

// get response -- this line will block until it is complete -- which is completely fine in an IntentService!
HttpResponse response = getHttpClient().execute(post);

int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    // something bad happened, request failed!
} else{
    // response was good, and "responseEntity" can be used for whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another call to the webservice which I call from either the UI or as part of the above process. what is the best way to approach this? should I not reuse my code and write it in two ways?

Comment: If you're uploading and don't care about the reply, it's easiest to use an `IntentService`. If you're downloading stuff or want a response, you should look into `ASyncTaskLoader`s